# How do I convert a yaml block to a json block with python?

Tags: python, json, yaml

I have this script that generates yaml data. I need it to produce the equivalent json data.

The code is this:

```
def main(argv):
        global top
        global version
        global package
        librivox_rest_url       = 'unknown'
        app_image_url           = 'unknown'
        password                = 'XXXXXXX'
        try:
              opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hl:t:v:k:p:i:",["url=","top=","version=","package=","password=","image_url="])
        except getopt.GetoptError:
              print 'make_hiera_data_from_librivox_api.py -l <librvox url> [-t <top>] [-v <version>] [-p <password>]'
              sys.exit(2)
        for opt, arg in opts:
                if opt == '-h':
                        usage ( 'Help called' )
                        sys.exit(0)
                elif opt in ("-l", "--url"):
                        librivox_rest_url = arg
                elif opt in ("-t", "--top"):
                        top = arg
                elif opt in ("-v", "--version"):
                        version = arg
                elif opt in ("-p", "--password"):
                        password = arg
                elif opt in ("-k", "--package"):
                        password = arg
                elif opt in ("-i", "--image_url"):
                        app_image_url = arg

        if ( librivox_rest_url == 'unknown' ):
                usage ("Please specify a librivox api url")
                sys.exit (1)
        if ( app_image_url == 'unknown' ):
                usage ("Please specify the app image url")
                sys.exit (1)

        parsed          = json.loads(requests.get(librivox_rest_url).text)
        book_key        = parsed['books'].keys()[0]
        apptitle        = parsed['books'][book_key]['title']
        app_image_url   = app_image_url
        app_zip_url     = parsed['books'][book_key]['url_zip_file']
        description     = parsed['books'][book_key]['description']
        yaml_version = """---
top: '%s'
package: '%s'
version: %s
password: '%s'
make_audiobook::package_name: "%%{hiera('package')}"
make_audiobook::description::description: %s

make_audiobook::version: "%%{hiera('version')}"
make_audiobook::mp3filesdir: "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}/res/raw"
make_audiobook::app_image::app_image_url: '%s'
make_audiobook::app_image::resource_path:  "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_image::appdir:  "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_image::appname:  "%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::appname:          "%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::password:         "%%{hiera('password')}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::apptitle:         "%s"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::package:          "%%{hiera('package')}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_code:     "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}/src/com/%%{hiera('package')}/%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_androidmanifest:     "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::version:          "%%{hiera('version')}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::tracks: """ % (top, package, version, password, description.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'), app_image_url, apptitle)

        for thing in get_filenames_from_zip_file (app_zip_url):
                if ( thing ):
                        yaml_version += " - %s\n" % thing

        print '''
make_audiobook::app_javacode::track_titles:
        '''.strip()
        for thing in parsed['books'][book_key]['sections']:
                yaml_version += " - %s\n" % (thing['title'])

        yaml_version += """
make_audiobook::create_project::workspace: "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::create_project::appname: "%%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::create_project::package_name: "%%{hiera('package')}"
make_audiobook::create_project::android: '/home/plankton/android-sdk-linux/tools/android'

make_audiobook::generate_keystore::top: "%%{hiera('top')}"
make_audiobook::generate_keystore::password: "%%{hiera('password')}"
make_audiobook::ant_debug::workspace: "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}"

make_audiobook::app_mp3files::app_zip_url: '%s'
make_audiobook::app_mp3files::resource_path:  "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}"

make_audiobook::app_drawables::path_to_drawables:  "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}/res/drawable-hdpi"
""" % (app_zip_url)

        print yaml_version
        print json.dumps( yaml_version, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

When I run the script I get this output where the json data is just one big long line. What am I doing wrong?

```
make_audiobook::app_javacode::track_titles:
---
top: '/home/get_links/TEMPLATE_FILES'
package: 'redcricket'
version: 1
password: 'XXXXXXX'
make_audiobook::package_name: "%{hiera('package')}"
make_audiobook::description::description: <p>"The Art of War is a Chinese military treatise written during the 6th century BC by Sun Tzu. Composed of 13 chapters, each of which is devoted to one aspect of warfare, it has long been praised as the definitive work on military strategies and tactics of its time. The Art of War is one of the oldest and most famous studies of strategy and has had a huge influence on both military planning and beyond. The Art of War has also been applied, with much success, to business and managerial strategies." (summary from Wikipedia)</p>

make_audiobook::version: "%{hiera('version')}"
make_audiobook::mp3filesdir: "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}/res/raw"
make_audiobook::app_image::app_image_url: 'https://ia801509.us.archive.org/7/items/song_of_the_wave_1703_librivox/songwave_1703.jpg'
make_audiobook::app_image::resource_path:  "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_image::appdir:  "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_image::appname:  "%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::appname:          "%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::password:         "%{hiera('password')}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::apptitle:         "Art of War"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::package:          "%{hiera('package')}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_code:     "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}/src/com/%{hiera('package')}/%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_androidmanifest:     "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::version:          "%{hiera('version')}"
make_audiobook::app_javacode::tracks:  - art_of_war_01-02_sun_tzu_64kb
 - art_of_war_03-04_sun_tzu_64kb
 - art_of_war_05-06_sun_tzu_64kb
 - art_of_war_07-08_sun_tzu_64kb
 - art_of_war_09-10_sun_tzu_64kb
 - art_of_war_11_sun_tzu_64kb
 - art_of_war_12-13_sun_tzu_64kb
 - 01 - Laying Plans / 02 - Waging War
 - 03 - Attack By Stratagem / 04 - Tactical Dispositions
 - 05 - Energy / 06 - Weak Points and Strong
 - 07 - Maneuvering / 08 - Variation in Tactics
 - 09 - The Army on the March / 10 - Terrain
 - 11 - The Nine Situations
 - 12 - The Attack By Fire / 13 - The Use of Spies

make_audiobook::create_project::workspace: "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::create_project::appname: "%{::appname}"
make_audiobook::create_project::package_name: "%{hiera('package')}"
make_audiobook::create_project::android: '/home/plankton/android-sdk-linux/tools/android'

make_audiobook::generate_keystore::top: "%{hiera('top')}"
make_audiobook::generate_keystore::password: "%{hiera('password')}"
make_audiobook::ant_debug::workspace: "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}"

make_audiobook::app_mp3files::app_zip_url: 'http://www.archive.org/download/art_of_war_librivox/art_of_war_librivox_64kb_mp3.zip'
make_audiobook::app_mp3files::resource_path:  "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}"

make_audiobook::app_drawables::path_to_drawables:  "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}/res/drawable-hdpi"

"---\ntop: '/home/get_links/TEMPLATE_FILES'\npackage: 'redcricket'\nversion: 1\npassword: 'XXXXXXX'\nmake_audiobook::package_name: \"%{hiera('package')}\"\nmake_audiobook::description::description: <p>\"The Art of War is a Chinese military treatise written during the 6th century BC by Sun Tzu. Composed of 13 chapters, each of which is devoted to one aspect of warfare, it has long been praised as the definitive work on military strategies and tactics of its time. The Art of War is one of the oldest and most famous studies of strategy and has had a huge influence on both military planning and beyond. The Art of War has also been applied, with much success, to business and managerial strategies.\" (summary from Wikipedia)</p>\n\nmake_audiobook::version: \"%{hiera('version')}\"\nmake_audiobook::mp3filesdir: \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}/res/raw\"\nmake_audiobook::app_image::app_image_url: 'https://ia801509.us.archive.org/7/items/song_of_the_wave_1703_librivox/songwave_1703.jpg'\nmake_audiobook::app_image::resource_path:  \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_image::appdir:  \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_image::appname:  \"%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::appname:          \"%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::password:         \"%{hiera('password')}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::apptitle:         \"Art of War\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::package:          \"%{hiera('package')}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_code:     \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}/src/com/%{hiera('package')}/%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_androidmanifest:     \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::version:          \"%{hiera('version')}\"\nmake_audiobook::app_javacode::tracks:  - art_of_war_01-02_sun_tzu_64kb\n - art_of_war_03-04_sun_tzu_64kb\n - art_of_war_05-06_sun_tzu_64kb\n - art_of_war_07-08_sun_tzu_64kb\n - art_of_war_09-10_sun_tzu_64kb\n - art_of_war_11_sun_tzu_64kb\n - art_of_war_12-13_sun_tzu_64kb\n - 01 - Laying Plans / 02 - Waging War\n - 03 - Attack By Stratagem / 04 - Tactical Dispositions\n - 05 - Energy / 06 - Weak Points and Strong\n - 07 - Maneuvering / 08 - Variation in Tactics\n - 09 - The Army on the March / 10 - Terrain\n - 11 - The Nine Situations\n - 12 - The Attack By Fire / 13 - The Use of Spies\n\nmake_audiobook::create_project::workspace: \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::create_project::appname: \"%{::appname}\"\nmake_audiobook::create_project::package_name: \"%{hiera('package')}\"\nmake_audiobook::create_project::android: '/home/plankton/android-sdk-linux/tools/android'\n\nmake_audiobook::generate_keystore::top: \"%{hiera('top')}\"\nmake_audiobook::generate_keystore::password: \"%{hiera('password')}\"\nmake_audiobook::ant_debug::workspace: \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}\"\n\nmake_audiobook::app_mp3files::app_zip_url: 'http://www.archive.org/download/art_of_war_librivox/art_of_war_librivox_64kb_mp3.zip'\nmake_audiobook::app_mp3files::resource_path:  \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}\"\n\nmake_audiobook::app_drawables::path_to_drawables:  \"%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}/%{::appname}/res/drawable-hdpi\" \n"
```

Comment: Your passing a *string* to `json.dumps`. The easiest way is to *deserialize your YAML* and then *serialize the resulting data-struture to JSON*. Also, why are you building a YAML string by hand? Just build a Python data structure and the serialize...

Comment: How do I deserialize my YAML and then serialize the resulting data-struture to JSON? Are you saying that I should follow these steps: 1) build a python data structure, 2) convert the python data structure to YAML 3) convert YAML data to JSON?  I was just try to skip a step and just do 1) build YAML data 2) convert to JSON.

Comment: Well, the easiest thing would be to just serialize to YAML and then JSON directly from the data structure. But since you already have a YAML, then presumably, you can just deserialize it then serialize the resulting data structure into a JSON .

Comment: Ok how do I serialize to YAML?

Comment: What? You already have a working YAML, no?

Comment: Yes I have working YAML in my string variable `yaml_version`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137894/discussion-between-red-cricket-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 1):

To generate yaml:

```
import yaml
data = {...}  # python datastructure
yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)  # second parameter specifies block style yaml.
```

to generate nicely indented json:

```
print json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

if you have yaml and want json:

```
print json.dumps(yaml.load(...), indent=4)
```